# Device screens @media queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have media query in CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (min-device-width: 320px)
```

When I open **elements inspector** in Google Chrome and select device **iPhone 4**, it shows different from the original iPhone 4s screen and some other phone screens.. Why? What do I do wrong?

How can I see the iPhone 4's original look of the page in my Google Chrome or other browsers? Is there any solutions?

How it looks on iPhone 4:
[image: How it shows in iPhone 4]

How it shows in Google Chrome, when I select device iPhone 4 (on the top left):
[image: how it shows in Google Chrome, when I select device: iPhone 4 (on the top left)]

Comment: iOS will never correspond exactly to [Chrome Emulator](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode#screen-emulator). Best way to it locally, if you have an iPhone, is using something like [Prepos](https://prepros.io/), where from you can mirror your website from your PC to any device connected to the same network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by adding a `<meta>` viewport tag to `<head>`

> `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">`

Now I don't have to use `(max-device-width: 480px) and (min-device-width: 320px)`

`(max-width: 480px) and (min-width: 320px)` <- work fine for all devices

Anyway, thank you all for your response.

Answer (score 1):

instead

```
(max-device-width: 480px) and (min-device-width: 320px)
```

use only

```
(max-width: 480px) and (min-width: 320px)
```

Why?

#### [`min/max-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#width)

> The width media feature describes the width of the rendering surface of
>   the output device (such as the width of the document window, or the
>   width of the page box on a printer).

#### [`min/max-device-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#device-width)

> Determines whether the output device is a grid device or a bitmap
>   device.  If the device is grid-based (such as a TTY terminal or a
>   phone display with only one font), the value is 1.  Otherwise it is
>   zero.

Comment: You know I need to make a responsive design. But if I use min/max-width with no *device* tag, when I open the page in iPhone, it looks like as on PC (http://wifi.ck.ua/screen.PNG).

Can you help me with that?

Comment: @Beqa—Have you included the meta element in the head of your page?

Comment: @Beqa can you show/provide your full code in order to help you better then? but it makes sense the comment above mention the `meta viewport` tag.. do you have it inside your `head` ?